# IE11 Border Issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have an `<h1>` tag with a solid *border*, but for some reason the *border* does not go all the way around the element. It happens sometimes on *IE11* and also when I reload the site it(*border) behaves weird, but sometimes it looks fine.

There's no consistency and it seems to happen randomly. Also when it does happen, the *border* stops at different points each time and it always near the end.

**HTML**:

```
<h1><span style="color:#FFFFFF"><span class="highlight">LOREM</span>&nbsp;IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET CONTETEUR</span></h1>
```

**CSS**:

```
.block h1 {
    border: solid 5px white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me ( jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fcLtxwsc/ ) maybe there are some other css commands that are causing the problem.

Comment: Like i said, it does not happen often. It happens once every 10 times, sometimes more or less. It's not consistent.

Comment: Does the problem appear/disappear as you resize the browser? Are you using a doctype? Which one?

Comment: No, the browser doesn't need to be resized. It happens instantly

Comment: My question was, does it happen as you resize it?

Comment: Nothing changes except the layout width as I resize the browser. The text still remains the same

Comment: My other question about the doctype.

Comment: What is the HTML and CSS around your H1 tag? Perhaps the google fonts is rendering the text slightly larger and your container around the H1 tag is hiding it.

Comment: Add the working code snippet with the issue, here or on http://jsfiddle.net, please.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full HTML and CSS files, after removing anything from the body that is not to do with the heading or its surrounds.  Please also remove from the CSS file any elements that are not referenced in the HTML file after you have edited it.

Comment: I'm positive that it's not a CSS or HTML issue as I've tried to alter the CSS and HTML as much as possible and the issue persists. Also most times the website loads perfectly fine, It's after every 10 or 15 reloads that the text issue happens across the website, not only with the element above. It happens almost 100% of the time when I test it using browserstack and less when testing on virtual machine via localhost.

Comment: the same issue was happend with my site

Comment: can you create a fiddle with full code for better understanding? @Shabbb

Answer (score 8):

If the issue was resolved with removing the web font, and only occurs intermittently when reloading; could this be caused by a timing inconsistency when refreshing? For instance, sometimes the font is loaded before the element is calculated (the good result) and sometimes after (resulting in the border being displayed based upon the boundary of what IE11 identifies as the fallback font).

Comment: This is a problem I have had with sites and it is due to the web font taking too long to load - most of the time it's fine but if for whatever reason it takes longer than normal then it causes issues like this.

Answer (score 4):

**Please add this class, it will work in IE :)**

```
.text-element-14 h1 span{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Try this and then add the border

Comment: I've already tried this and it doesn't work. It happens across the page with almost all the text being mispositioned.

Answer (score 2):

Since I haven't been able to reproduce the issue, while in IE 11, I suggest changing the way you nest the elements. Instead of

```
<h1>
    <span style="color:#FFFFFF">
        <span class="highlight">LOREM</span>
        &nbsp;IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET CONTETEUR
    </span>
</h1>
```

I'd go for

```
<h1 style="color:#FFFFFF">
    <span class="highlight">LOREM</span>
    &nbsp;IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET CONTETEUR
</h1>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

This is probably happening only when developer tools are open and testing locally, and even then not regularly. You can observe this behavior also in IE10, where it does happen as well (just not as often as in IE11).

I think this is one of the most weird bugs in the recent history of IE, and it's not like that's an easy challenge, also i couldn't find it mentioned in any docs or how to workaround this properly. I just remember this bug from some time ago, and since it didn't make any problems in production for people without developer tools activated, we left it the way it was.

Though from my understanding of the problem, i think it could be solved by creating an HTML inline element and get its size before DOM ready/webfont loaded, then start an interval to check for changed HTML inline element size and trigger and revert a DOM change on that element. Let me know if you need help with making a script, just in case, but i think you'll not be able to reproduce this issue on the production version so i'm not sure if you're still interested in solving this.

Answer (score 2):

```
.text-element-14 h1 span {
     border: solid 5px white;
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
     margin: 0;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I did a little research and believe that it's a bug in IE. If you change the h1 to a p tag then make the font the size you desire it will render correctly.

Here is the site I found the info at. https://css-tricks.com/ie-css-bugs-thatll-get-you-every-time/

You could also try this meta tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

I can't reproduce the error but this was awarded a bounty here
https://superuser.com/questions/838802/ie11-renders-elements-with-border-radius-incorrectly

Answer (score 2):

Check out Bootstrap class ".clearfix"